# (str1[i] || str2[i]) what does this mean, can someone explain

Tags: string, anagram

I am trying to find out if two strings are anagrams or not and these piece of code verifies if they are of equal length or not. How?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: The language is C++. str1 and str2 are two string, (str1[i] || str2[i]) is to check if two strings are of equal length. I just wanted to know how that logic works

Answer (score 0):

str1 is a (char) array.
str2 is a (char) array.

This code checks if:

index `i` exists on `str1`

-OR-
index `i` exists on `str2`

If your two arrays were
`['a', 'b', 'c']`
`['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']`

It will likely check index 0 first

```
i=0 // 'a' exists
i=1 // 'b' exists
i=3 // 'c' exists
i=4 // 'z' exists - first didn't match, so checks second
i=5 // doesn't exist
i=6 // doesn't exist
i=7 // doesn't...
```

Comment: How is it ensuring that the strings are of equal length?

Comment: @Payal04 it doesn't

Comment: @Payal04 I posted what the code does, it doesn't check length equality.